# Does the inhibitor obelisk from EnderIO use energy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have one, but he is always full and I removed the power cable and he continues to work. I don't really mind, but this seems weird.

Comment: I figured that this would be answered by a wiki, but instead it just gets more ambiguous. This is a list of obelisks for EnderIO, and they are in their own category under "machines" outside of the Powered and Unpowered machines https://github.com/SleepyTrousers/EnderIO/wiki/List-of-Obelisks and two of them have FTB wiki pages. The Attractor Obelisk requires power https://ftbwiki.org/Attractor_Obelisk but the wiki does not say for the Aversion Obelisk https://ftbwiki.org/Aversion_Obelisk

Comment: AFAIK, machines usally have an internal power buffer. Have you checked that one is empty too?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes the Inhibitor Obelisk uses Redstone Flux (RF)

There are many reasons your obelisk continues to work without an active power supply.

First, the internal power buffer could be full. This is like an inbuilt battery inside the machine.

[image: Picture of power buffer with 5040RF]

If that is empty, and the obelisk is still functioning, it could be passively being powered.
Ensure that there aren't any wireless RF transmitters nearby.

There could be a capacitor underneath the obelisk - somewhere all of us often forget to check. Machines can also be powered by each other, so even if your machine doesn't have its own power cable, if a adjacent machine is receiving power, it can pass it's power to the obelisk.

Finally, your obelisk could be bugged out - This can be fixed easily by breaking and replacing.

Feel free to reply/edit.